# Connection interruption issue with Galaxybase graph database client

Tags: graph-databases

I'm encountering an issue while using the Galaxybase graph database. The error message I receive is "Connection with [127.0.0.1] will interrupt, client did not consume buffer more than 900000 milliseconds."

```
Here's  the code I'm using to connect to the Galaxybase graph database:

import com.galaxybase.driver.GraphDatabase;
import com.galaxybase.driver.GraphSession;

public class GraphDBExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GraphDatabase graphDB = new GraphDatabase("127.0.0.1"); // Connect to the local Galaxybase graph database
            GraphSession session = graphDB.createSession();

            // Execute query or operation statements
            session.execute("MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n");

            session.close(); // Close the session

            graphDB.close(); // Close the database connection
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Verify if it is caused by wrong code-writing, making it fail to properly consume all the data.
2. If there is any business that needs longer processing time, you can adjust it through the configuration "write.controller.max.waiting". The default value is 900,000 ms.